# how to get value of datagridview then will be fetch by the another window form

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm creating an ordering system and I add datagridview to view the data on my database and listview to input the orders, when I double click rows on my datagridview, mealname will be transferred to listview on index 0, the quantity and totalprice is from another windowform but I can't get the original price per piece, It always get 0 value.

here is my code on my datagridview

```
public void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            String mealname = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + String.Empty;
            String price1 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + String.Empty;
            listView1.Items.Add(mealname);
            qtyOfOrders orders = new qtyOfOrders();
            orders.Show();
        }
```

here is my code for my new windowform when datagridview is doubleclicked

```
`private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cashier c = new cashier();
        if (c.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int row = c.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int col = c.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; 
            c.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(c.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString()));
            c.qtyOrder.ListView.Items.Add(QTYNumber.Text);
            int qtyToInt = Convert.ToInt32(QTYNumber.Text);
            int priceToInt = Convert.ToInt32(c.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
            int totalPrice = qtyToInt * priceToInt;
            c.qtyOrder.ListView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(QTYNumber.Text);
            c.price.ListView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(totalPrice.ToString());
        }
    }`
```

[image: first window form with datagridview and list view]

[image: after I double click the datagridview]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem hard :)

```
 int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; //This gets the row index(or count) of the selected row
 int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; //This gets the column index(or count) of the selected row

 form2.Listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString()); ///Finally inserts the column's data/value in the listview :)
```

Ow,and about the double click ,make sure to put this code in `MouseDoubleClick` event :)

**A few fixes in your code**

```
   int qtyToInt = Convert.ToInt32(QTYNumber.Text);

   int priceToInt = Convert.ToInt32(c.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
   int totalPrice = qtyToInt * priceToInt;
```

Comment: can you explain this?
by the way, I'm doing the manipulation of quantity and price in the second window form then it will inputted on the listview of my first windom form after I click OK button

Comment: @JustineCortez , take a look at it now and mark it as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: where should I insert it in my second form? is it before `if` function or I will replace the `if` function by this and add the other statement inside the `if` function?

Comment: As you aid you want to add the cell value to the listview when you double click the dgvw, just put it in the `MouseDoubleClick` event of the dgvw in form1 ...

Comment: yes I want to add that, but I need to calculate first for the total price and total quantity of the ordered items before I add it to the list view that's why I use another form and I think the one you give to me is only applicable on the first form?

Comment: give an example of how your dgvw looks and what is you expected result

Comment: I edit my post. please see picture of the second form because it will get the quantity of ordered meals and then calculate the total price based on the quantity ordered.

Comment: @JustineCortez , re-check my answer :)

Comment: still not functioning, insert it in my second form.

Comment: @JustineCortez , do u mean it doesn't insert or is it 0 ?

Comment: it doesn't insert, i try to do put breakpoint on the seond window form on  `private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` it value still 0.

Comment: firstly , where are you putting the code ? 2ndly , what is the value of `QTYNumber.Text` ?

Comment: I add the codes you give in the second form(Order Quantity), the value of the `QTYNumber.text` is depends on the user, but it is on the second form also, the `+ and -` button is the one who add and subtract the quantity to be inputted by the user.

Comment: i put the code in datagridview but the value insert to the listview is zero, how can I get the quantity value in form 2 and will be transferred to datagridview_doubleclick event so it will be inserted correctly

Comment: you are something wrong somewhere ..... try combining my code with yours....there's no reason that u'll get 0